# Upgrade to EF Core 7 get Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: ''.'

Tags: entity-framework-core

I upgrade Ef core 6 to 7 and get this error at Database.EnsureCreated();

```
public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) 
{
    Database.EnsureCreated();
    if (Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
    {
        Database.Migrate(); 
    }                 
}
```

The database is created but I get this error. I fear if some migrations are ended with an error and are not complete. and I want these codes always be here and not commented after first run. What is this error and how to correct it?

Edits:
I deleted all content of the Migrations folder and the Sqlite Db and created an Initial migration, But when I want to apply this migration I get the same error.
I get this error after Updating Database by a Migration or at the line:

if (Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any()):

```
SQLite provider.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'main' on server 'C:\Users\...\Documents\Developer\WinForms Blazor2_2022_Book_Secure_Active\WinFormsBlazor\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows\AppData\AppDB.db'.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: ''.
```

I created a AppData\AppDB.db in root project folder and set this db to Copy always then in the Onconfiguring in the DbContext:

```
if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {                
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))}\\AppData\\AppDB.db"
            , options =>
            {
                options.UseNetTopologySuite();
            });
        }
```

I have no main Database, I don't understand why I have this setup worked in EF Core 6 for a year but after updating to 7 it is not working! any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: [Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying#apply-migrations-at-runtime). Don't call EnsureCreated() before Migrate(). EnsureCreated() bypasses Migrations to create the schema, which causes Migrate() to fail. [DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated). Note that this API does **not** use migrations to create the database. In addition, the database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations.

Comment: I removed EnsureCreated but the same error appears at next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're hitting issue [#29584](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29584). It will hopefully be fixed in version 7.0.3.

For now, you can work around it by manually updating the SQLitePCLRaw dependency:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.NetTopologySuite" Version="7.0.2" />

  <!-- Manually updated to fix NetTopologySuite issues -->
  <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I updated all packages including pclraw but I get error: GenericArguments[0], 'WinFormsBlazor.Migrations.AppDbContexts.Point', on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteGeometryTypeMapping`1[TGeometry]' violates the constraint of type 'TGeometry'.

Comment: I changed the name of migration from Point to Loc and above error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem was using `x => { x.UseNetTopologySuite(); }` in the `UseSqlite` function when adding the ef core context, When `UseNetTopologySuite()` is there, Any access to the database give error: `SQLite Error 1: ''.` and if I remove `UseNetTopologySuite()` I get another error: `sqlite error 1: 'no such function: initspatialmetadata'.`.

In Ef core 6.0.12 there is no problem and I can use Spatial Point type without any problems, even after migrating that includes a point type, several tables and views related to geometry are created automatically with Ef core 6.

I had to forget using Spatial types in EF Core 7 so that I can upgrade my EF core version.